# Problema Sweet Alert -Angular 4

Tags: angular, sweetalert2

Estoy usando SweetAlert2 en un proyecto de Angular 4:

**Instalación:**

```
npm i sweetalert2
```

Estoy usando varias importaciones por que ninguna funciona, primero uso esta:

```
import  Swal  from "sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js";
```

Mi código es este en una función:

```
//BORRA PEDIDO
  DeletePedido(event, idX){
    console.log("****Borra Pedido****");


    
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'BORRADO',
      text: "Desea eliminar este pedido?!",
      icon: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
    }as any).then((result) => {
      if (result.isConfirmed) {
        this.pedidosServices.eliminaPedido(idX)
                      .subscribe(
                          data => {
                            this.flagEliminado = data;
                              console.log(this.flagEliminado);
                              if(this.flagEliminado==true){
                                Swal.fire(
                                  'Hecho!',
                                  'Se elimino el pedido!',
                                  'success'
                                )
                                var td = event.target.parentNode; 
                                var tr = td.parentNode; // la fila que se va a remover
                                tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
                              }else{
                                Swal.fire(
                                  'ERROR!',
                                  'Hubo un problema eliminando el pedido!',
                                  'error'
                                )
                              }
                              
                          }
                      );
      }
    })
```

No me genera error pero la pagina carga así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si uso la siguiente importación:

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
```

El código no compila y da este error:

**ERROR TERMINAL**

```
ERROR in D:/Documents/P3W_ANGULAR GUATEMALA/P3W_ANGULAR GUATEMALA/V2/P3W-FE-Actualizada/node_modules/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.d.ts (277,30): Cannot find name 'readonly'.
ERROR in D:/Documents/P3W_ANGULAR GUATEMALA/P3W_ANGULAR GUATEMALA/V2/P3W-FE-Actualizada/src/app/mainSite/pedidos-control/pedidos-control.component.ts (98,14): Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Promise<SweetAlertResult<{}>>'. 
ERROR in D:/Documents/P3W_ANGULAR GUATEMALA/P3W_ANGULAR GUATEMALA/V2/P3W-FE-Actualizada/node_modules/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.d.ts (164,47): '{' or ';' expected.
ERROR in D:/Documents/P3W_ANGULAR GUATEMALA/P3W_ANGULAR GUATEMALA/V2/P3W-FE-Actualizada/node_modules/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.d.ts (277,39): '=' expected.
ERROR in D:/Documents/P3W_ANGULAR GUATEMALA/P3W_ANGULAR GUATEMALA/V2/P3W-FE-Actualizada/node_modules/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.d.ts (346,23): ';' expected.
ERROR in D:/Documents/P3W_ANGULAR GUATEMALA/P3W_ANGULAR GUATEMALA/V2/P3W-FE-Actualizada/node_modules/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.d.ts (346,45): ';' expected.
```

Como puedo arreglar esto?

Comment: Revisaste la compatibilidad de sweet alert con angular ?

Comment: La primera importación es correcta, pero tambien tienes que jalar los estilos. Lo puedes hacer en tu index.html o angular.json, dentro de styles.

Comment: 1) npm uninstall sweetalert2 2) npm i sweetalert2 El import debe de ser: import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

Comment: @Legna si es compatible, yo lo uso en muchos proyectos, desde Angular7-Angular13, en todos funciona OK